# windows 10 Search Windows 6lrv0k Avatars. Where did it come from? How to get rid of it?

Tags: windows-10

Hi please have a look at the image. In Windows 10 these Avatar Heads show up in the window 6lrv0k .

I thought it must be some Malware but Malwarebytes did not find anything.

[image: Avatar heads]

Comment: What is this 6lrv0k window - where did it come from?

Comment: It looks like part of the software

Comment: @RohitGupta - You mean the start menu and Contacts? I can only assume that 6lrv0k is the name of the AD domain and/or the organization.

Comment: Isn't that Windows Search recent results? I found Linkedin profiles for all these people. They're employed by Contoso Electroncis. Which is a fictional company of [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/contoso-overview?view=o365-worldwide), used in the Office product training materials for at least a decade. Maybe that gives a clue where these might originate? Nothing on 6lrv0k tho'.

Comment: Thanks... But how did i activate it in the first place and how do I deactivate it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was just to switched to my Microsoft office account to my other Microsoft email account. I did so by going to my account con and clicking on it The 6lrv0k was part of the email account that was automatically generated by MS office.

I think under Manage accounts you could even delete it.

@Peregrino69 thanks for the hint.

[image: solution]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).